# MKMapView not calling to update insets on iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, ios9.3

I have a `MKMapView` inside of a navigation controller in my app. Under iOS 9.2, I was correctly seeing the little map compass view appear below my navigation bar when I would rotate the map view.

Under iOS 9.3, the compass appears to be under the navigation bar. To confirm this, I've overridden `topLayoutGuide` in the view controller for my map view, and can see that it is *not* being called by the `MKMapView`, when it was in iOS 9.2 (to update the insets for the map).  Here's the call stack under iOS 9.2:

[image: iOS 9.2 call stack to topLayoutGuide]

When run under iOS 9.3, this call from `_updateInsets` is never made. Is this a bug (e.g. should I file an Apple Radar), or did something fundamentally change with map insets, and now I need to actively set them?  I did not see anything in the documentation.

Thanks!

EDIT: It should be noted that I am not using storyboards, or auto-layout. It's an older project that I haven't converted to these things yet.

Comment: I just used Xcode 8 to build under iOS 10, and this issue appears to have been fixed for now in this version. Will keep an eye on it as the betas progress. Perhaps they will fix it in a 9.x.x release in the interim, if they've back-ported it.